# Retornar dados com base na array | PHP

Tags: php, array

Desenvolvi a seguinte função em PHP:

```
function getTiposInsumos(){
    return [
        [ "nome" => "Nenhum",               "codigo" => 1],
        [ "nome" => "Metro Quadrado (M²)",  "codigo" => 2],
        [ "nome" => "Metro Cúbico (M³)",    "codigo" => 3],
        [ "nome" => "Pacote (PCT)",         "codigo" => 4],
        [ "nome" => "Metro (M)",            "codigo" => 5],
        [ "nome" => "Peça (PÇ)",            "codigo" => 6],
    ];
}
```

Gostaria de criar uma nova função, onde eu buscaria de acordo com o codigo repassado

Comment: `array_filter(getTiposInsumos(), fn($n) => $n["codigo"] == 5);` - https://onlinephp.io/c/4b111

Comment: @CypherPotato Grato por sua colaboração. É quase isso, porém, quero exibir como retorno somente o nome, com base no ID repassado.

Comment: Depois de obter uma lista filtrada você pode obter os valores e o índice: ```array_values($lista_filtrada)[0]["nome"]```

Answer (score -2):

```
function getTiposInsumos($id){
    $array = [
        [ "nome" => "Nenhum",               "codigo" => 0],
        [ "nome" => "Metro Quadrado (M²)",  "codigo" => 1],
        [ "nome" => "Metro Cúbico (M³)",    "codigo" => 2],
        [ "nome" => "Pacote (PCT)",         "codigo" => 3],
        [ "nome" => "Metro (M)",            "codigo" => 4],
        [ "nome" => "Peça (PÇ)",            "codigo" => 5],
    ];

    $return = $array[$id];

    return (object)$return;
}

print_r(getTiposInsumos(3)->codigo);
```